# What does this statement mean: p fixes each j not in $\{i, p(i), ... , p^k(i-1)\}$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

> Definition:A permutation p is a k-cycle if there exists $k\gt 0$ and an integer i such that:
>
> •k is the smallest positive integer such that $p^k(i)=i$
>
> •p fixes each j not in $\{i, p(i), ... , p^k(i-1)\}$

I don't understand what the second statement means. What do they mean by fixing j's? Can someone explain it?(I'M OK W/ THIS PART)

Also what about this definition: Two permutations p and s are disjoint if each number moved by p is fixed by s or equivalently each number moved by s is fixed by p ? How is an element of a permutation being fixed by another permutation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p$ is a permutation and $j$ is an element, "$p$ fixes $j$" means $p(j)=j$. The set is just the set of elements you can reach starting from $i$ and applying the permutation some number of times, so it's saying everything else stays where it is when you apply $p$.

Comment: Can you give an example of a such permutation?

Comment: And still I can't get the sense about it. How should I interpret that statement ?

Comment: @LeylaAlkan Sure, the permutation acting on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ which sends $1$ to $4$,  $2$ to $1$, $3$ to $3$, $4$ to $2$ and $5$ to $5$. Here $i=1$, $k=3$, $\{i,p(i),p^2(i)\}=\{1,4,2\}$ and so we need $p(j)=j$ for each $j$ not in that set, i.e. $p(3)=3$ and $p(5)=5$, which is true.

Comment: What about this definition: Two permutations p and s are disjoint if each number moved by p is fixed by s or equivalently each number moved by s is fixed by p ?